# What's the deal with Dutch (one of Johnny's Friends) from the Original KARATE KID?

Tags: film-industry

I just wonder what's the matter with the Character "Dutch" from the Original Karate Kid. He enjoyed picking on Daniel and it seemed like he had Mental Disorder. Why did he become very angry and try to attack Daniel in the Locker Room before the Tournament and why was he silent when Kreese placed Johnny in the Chokehold?

Comment: He just seemed like your garden variety bully, a lacky of Johnny's.

Comment: Well, he  _is_ Steve McQueen's son.  This might explain the anger management issues ;)

Comment: Juiced up on 'roids.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at Johnny's friends they all have their own personalities.  Two friends specifially seem to be the "good angel, bad angel" on Johnny's shoulder.  Dutch was the bad angel encouraging Johnny to be ruthless and to teach Daniel a lesson.  Bobby on the other hand is more of the good angel. Most of the time he is trying to tell Johnny to let Daniel go or to forget about things all together.  In the tournament Kreese asked Bobby specifically to fight dirty and he had a problem with doing it.  Dutch would've not only have no problem taking him out of commission but would've seriously hurt Daniel doing it.  Luckily for Daniel he already eliminated Dutch earlier.

I wouldn't say Dutch had a mental disorder, he was just in a group of boys that had a bad mentor.  He was also probably afraid of Kreese so he didn't do anything.